# MVC3 RouteUrl inside a ViewModel

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, controller, asp.net-mvc-routing

I need to create a route URL based on parameters as a part of a JSON return values.

What is the equivalent of Url.RouteUrl but to be used inside the controller code,
So I can return a string in my Json result that contains the routeurl .

I need this done outside of the controller class, in a separate class, can this be done at all?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can still use `Url.RouteUrl`, but in a slightly different way.

Place a `using System.Web.Mvc;` at the top of your class (of course, you might need to Add Reference to *System.Web.Mvc*).

Then get the Url object by:

```
UrlHelper Url = new UrlHelper(HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext);
```

and access as usual: `Url.RouteUrl`.